# Where does the Ubuntu 18.04 Dock look for apps and app icons?

Tags: 18.04, snap, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

Snap apps that I've installed do not appear in my Dock. I'm trying to find the environment variables I need to set to fix this.

I read that the Dock uses `XDG_DATA_DIRS` env var to source the apps that appear in the Dock, and I've ensured that `/var/lib/snapd/desktop`, which contains snap `.desktop` files, is appended to that path, but this does not resolve my issue.

The relevant customizations I've made to a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 installation (that I think could possibly interfere with this) include:

- zsh
- Wayland
- Communitheme

Comment: I had the same problem when I changed my default shell from /bin/bash to /bin/zsh with `chsh`. There is more information in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1318722/on-ubuntu-18-04-snap-apps-dont-appear-in-the-app-launcher)

Answer (score 0):

I think most of the desktop files are in `/usr/share/applications` but i dont know if ALL of them are there or where it stores the list of apps on the dock.